# T-SQL Equivalent of regular expression '\b'

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm in the process of converting a CLR function that utilizes regex to a SQL function. I know that SQL Server does not fully support regex, but i just need one case to work which is a word search.

Search Field Value: `{"Id":1234, "Title": "The quick brown"}`

Regex Pattern in .NET: `'\b' + '"Id":1234' '\b'`

I want to be able to match when Search field contains **"Id":1234** but not **"Id":12345**

How do  I achieve this? I've tried this but obviously doesn't work when the number 1234 ends with space or b instead of comma.

```
DECLARE @match bit = 0
DECLARE @input nvarchar(max) = '{"Id":1234, "Title": "The quick brown"}'
DECLARE @pattern nvarchar(max) ='"Id":1234'

SELECT @match = 1 FROM (VALUES ('')) table1 (column1)
        WHERE @Input LIKE '%' + @pattern + ',%'
```

Comment: T-SQL doesn't support REGEX; period. It supports *basic* pattern matching and that's all. If you need to use some kind of REGEX functionality in SQL Server you'll need to use a CLR function (there are plenty of examples of these for REGEX out there).

Comment: @Larnu I've specifically said in my question that SQL Server does not support regex but I don't need full Regex support. I also said that i'm converting the CLR function, then you'll tell me to use CLR function?

Comment: That doesn't change my point though. SQL Server only supports basic pattern matching, and if you want more than that, then you need REGEX, or something similar; which needs a CLR. I am reiterating that fact, as if you knew that you wouldn't be asking how to replication REGEX functionality with T-SQL's basic pattern matching.

Comment: @Larnu exactly my point, I only need basic pattern matching. We created the CLR because we knew that it will cover broad pattern matching, but now that we're migrating to Azure SQL w/c doesn't support CLR, we have to convert the CLR, hence the question. Of course I don't expect full REGEX functionality, hence the specific case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think pattern `'%"Id":1234[^a-zA-Z0-9]%'` will do.

It uses negated character class `[^a-zA-Z0-9]`, which works as in regular regex :)

Sample:

```
declare @tbl table (col varchar(100));
insert into @tbl values 
('{"Id":1234, "Title": "The quick brown"}'),
('{"Id":1234, "Title": "The quick brown"}'), 
('Id":1234, "Title": "The quick brown"}'), 
('{"Id":12345, "Title": "The quick brown"}');

select *
from @tbl
where col like '%"Id":1234[^a-zA-Z0-9]%'
```

Comment: Looks good, I don't expect a letter next to the id but the additional guard is appreciated.

Comment: @james I tried to imitate word boundary :) You could also use another guard and allow when `1234` is at the end of string, something like `where ... or col like '%"Id":1234'`

Comment: @MichałTurczyn You don't need such a guard assuming the OP only has well formed JSON.  Also, your answer is basically identical to mine, but given 15 minutes later.

Answer (score 4):

Considering you have JSON data, why not parse it as such?

```
DECLARE @JSON nvarchar(MAX) = '{"Id":1234, "Title": "The quick brown"}';

SELECT *
FROM (VALUES(@JSON)) V(J)
     CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(@JSON)
     WITH (Id int,
           Title varchar(50)) OJ
WHERE OJ.Id = 1234;
```

Comment: Then we need more examples, @james . You've only given us one here, so I made the assumption it's always JSON. Checking a value is valid JSON or xml is simple enough though.

Answer (score 2):

In general, parsing JSON content with regex alone is not ideal.  We might be able to use SQL Server's enhanced `LIKE` operator here:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE json LIKE '%"Id":1234[^5]%';
```

This would return all occurrences of `"Id":1234` which are followed by any character other than 5.  Note that there should always be at least one character after a match, since the key value pair needs to be closed in the JSON.

### Demo

Comment: number could range from 0 - 999999, so the number succeeding the 1234 could range from 0-9. Hmm maybe [^0-9] should do the trick. I'll try that - okay that works, not flexible but I'll feed it more inputs.

Comment: @james Regarding the word boundaries, you might not actually those assuming the JSON is well formed.  As a disclaimer, parsing JSON with regex is generally bad, but sometimes we have to live with it.